When using AnimatedContainer with width property, the Text inside the AnimatedContainer is visible even if the width is zero, why is this happening?
This When using AnimatedContainer with width property, the Text inside the AnimatedContainer is visible even if the width is zero. The container is hidden but the Text is not.
This this the code
Obx(() {
                    // if ( menuBarController.isMenuVisible.value ) {

       return AnimatedContainer(
        // clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        // Animation curve
                        height:500,
                        width: menuBarController.isMenuVisible.value ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-80 : 0,

                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        child: Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          color: CustomColors.primaryBackground,
                          

                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            // if ( menuBarController.isMenuVisible.value ) 
                            GestureDetector(onDoubleTap: () {
                          print("tapped");
                          Get.to(()=>const AboutPage());
                          menuBarController.toggleMenu();

                        },
                        child: Text("About"),)],),
                        )
                      )
                      
                      
                      ;}),

This the problem I am experiencingenter image description here 

enter image description here  when I use text inside the AnimatinContainer it is showing even if I give it zero width

by default, container's size depends on its children, if you want to hide the text then define the check on container child widget, to hide or show the text.

Use AnimatedOpacity Widget, to toggle when to show the text widget.
You can use Visibility Widget but it shows the initial text same as your screenshot. So, I think AnimatedOpacity goes better with AnimatedContainer.
AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          height: 500,
          width: _show ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80 : 0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          child: AnimatedOpacity(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            opacity: _show ? 1 : 0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onDoubleTap: () {},
                  child: const Text("About"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ), 
        ),

